# Library javadocs generated by maven-javadoc-plugin does not work when linked on Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-plugin

**UPDATE1:** It is not just parameter names, eclipse does not display any javadoc information at all. When you hover over a class nothing is displayed.

**UPDATE2:** My eclipse  version is 4.2.0.

I'm using Eclipse and I would like to attach a library's javadocs to my project so that when I implement an interface and choose the option *Add unimplemented methods* the **methods parameter names** show up correctly instead of *arg0*, *arg1*, etc.

Problem is:

- When I generate the javadocs through eclipse (Project > Generate Javadocs...) and link it to my project **it works**, in other words, I see the correct method parameter names.
- When I generate the javadocs through maven-javadoc-plugin and link it to my project **it does not work**, in other words, I see *arg0*, *arg1*, etc.

Perhaps I'm not configuring my maven-javadoc-plugin correctly? Below the configuration from my *pom.xml*:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Not seeing the parameter names is very bad.

Comment: Have you tried cracking open the jar files and comparing the files?  How were they different?  Just as an aside, I believe most IDEs, including Eclipse, will rely primarily on the *source* jar for this kind of intelligence.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll do a diff and see what I can find. But I won't be distributing the sources, just the javadocs. The javadocs generated by eclipse work fine, so maven is doing something different for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has to do with [this eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394382) that was only fixed in version 4.3. Basically eclipse stops processing a javadoc html file on the following line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
```

because it is expecting the charset in the content attribute like below:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

I don't think there is a way to tell the maven javadoc plugin to change this meta tag, but you can run an ANT task below from maven to fix all your html files:

```
<replace dir="target/apidocs">
    <include name="**/*.html"/>
    <replacetoken><![CDATA[<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">]]></replacetoken>
    <replacevalue><![CDATA[<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">]]></replacevalue>
</replace>
```